# is there a good way to display log messages in a shell?

Tags: shell, logging, command-line

I am writing a system where I will have a little shell to interact with a server, and the server plus some other stuff will log some messages. The issue is that i get stuff like that:
`> lsII 2013-12-07T13:09:05.597 Server waiting for start signal..`
`> st`
 `> DD 2013-12-07T13:09:07.282 Server got start signal.`
`DD 2013-12-07T13:09:07.282 Server starting up..`
`II 2013-12-07T13:09:07.282 Server running..`
`stop`
`> II 2013-12-07T13:09:10.25 Server stopping..`
`exit`
I get commands that I write cut off, etc.
Is there a way to make it look prettier? like have the prompt on the bottom line, and logs get displayed above it? The only solution I thought that could work, is to log to a file, and then have two terminals, one for the prompt, the other to `cat` the logfile, which I don't like very much.

Comment: Another form of cat misuse :)
Have a look at tail for displaying the log file.
Realizing a prompted programm isn't new stuff aswell, there are libs that help with that...(syncing output and prompt/input) So why need two terminals at all? But, of course we don't even know on what kind of system you are working... How does your current logging procedure look like? Have you tried the solution you have proposed yourself? What were the results?

Comment: i know `cat` is not the best, but I generally would like a better way than having to display the contents of a logfile. I'd rather have them inside my shell, but in a way that can be displayed without disrupting the use of the shell.

Comment: ok, what is your shell?

Comment: nothing fancy for now. https://gist.github.com/pvinis/7840124 something like that. I just want to send a few simple commands to process that is running.

Comment: Okaay, well what you need is an IO layer in your application. It will provide a few procedures to send output to the console and a few to receive input from it. It will print the prompt, and if any other output has to be displayed, it will override the prompt and reprint it later
Also a logging layer would be great, best implemented with a tracer so you know where the message comes from.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem some years ago.  Here's how I solved it (read my question and then the accepted answer): [GNU Readline: how to clear the input line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512028/gnu-readline-how-to-clear-the-input-line)

Basically, you probably have something like `select()` multiplexing stdin for the prompt with the network connection to the server.  You can organize something to remember what the user has typed so far, and if a server message comes in the middle, backspace the line, clear it, print the new server message, then add a newline and re-display the user's input.  This worked quite well for me, and gave a believable illusion that the server messages were being printed "above" the prompt.