# inputrc file cannot be loaded

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh, rc

I just figured out we can create a `~/.inputrc` file to define keyboard mappings. But I don't know how to load it. I tried to source it but I get a 'set Syntax Error' immediately. I copied the `~/.inputrc` file from here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.2/chapter07/inputrc.html

It mentions that it is loaded using Readline. What does that mean?

Comment: I have an inputrc that I run with, and if I try to source it I get "command not found" errors from bash... but it loads and works fine when I create a new terminal.

Comment: do you mind copying your .inputrc contents here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readline is one of [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693670/23118) possible "keyboard input handling frontends" that a program might use. A program might also use none (other than the usual stdio handling done by libc).

As mentioned, `.inputrc` is used by readline, so it will only affect programs that use readline. Bash is such a program, so it will use `.inputrc` indirectly, but it is not a file that you will source like files as `.bashrc`, and the syntax is not related at all.
The `.inputrc` file is only loaded (indirectly though the readline library) by the program at startup. From [the documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9):

> When a program which uses the Readline library starts up, the init
>   file is read, and the key bindings are set.

Answer (score 8):

```
 $ bind -f ~/.inputrc
```

`-f  filename`:    Read key bindings from `filename`.

```
 $ help bind
```

**Notes:** It's a built-in bash command, so it will only work with `bash` or `sh`. It won't work with `ksh` or `csh` shell, for tcsh or csh shell you need to use `bindkey` command. For more help: [bindkey](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_11.html)

Comment: when i do `$ bind` it says command not found. however `$ help bind` actually seems to have instructions for it.. I'm confused. Do you know by default where the bind binary is located ?

Comment: bind is built into bash, run man bash

Comment: what is your OS version or vendor?

Comment: are you using bash shell or other shell?

Comment: I'm running c shell on Linux

Comment: The C shell does not use Readline, so `.inputrc` is irrelevant to you.

Comment: so what does c shell use to define key bindings then?

Comment: bindkey  - This is different method to define keymap, check my edited answer

Comment: @Satish: you linked to the `zsh` documentation, which at best will be accidentally relevant to `bindkey` in `csh`.