# How do I get the readline() to work in an ncurses window?

Tags: c++, c, terminal, readline, ncurses

I have a small test program as follow trying to get a two window `ncurses` screen to work with `readline()`.

When I call `readline()`, the typing works, but I can't see it. Somehow the echoing is lost. With the `getch()` (if you don't `#define READLINE`) then the typing appears at the  wrong place.

Is there a way to get `readline()` to work along `ncurse`?

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

#define READLINE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WINDOW * main_win = initscr();

    int screen_width(1), screen_height(1);
    getmaxyx(main_win, screen_height, screen_width);

    wborder(main_win, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mvwaddch(main_win, screen_height - 6, 0, ACS_LTEE);
    mvwhline(main_win, screen_height - 6, 1, ACS_HLINE, screen_width - 2);
    mvwaddch(main_win, screen_height - 6, screen_width - 1, ACS_RTEE);
    mvwprintw(main_win, 0, 2, " Output Window ");
    mvwprintw(main_win, screen_height - 6, 2, " Input Window ");
    wrefresh(main_win);

    WINDOW * win0 = newwin(screen_height - 8, screen_width - 2, 1, 1);
    WINDOW * win1 = newwin(4, screen_width - 2, screen_height - 5, 1);

    wrefresh(win0);
    wrefresh(win1);

    scrollok(win0, TRUE);
    scrollok(win1, TRUE);

    for(;;)
    {
        mvwprintw(win1, 3, 0, "tcp> ");
        wrefresh(win1);

#ifndef READLINE
        char c(getch());
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            scroll(win1);
        }
#else
        char * l(readline(""));
        char c(*l);
        if(c == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        scroll(win1);
#endif

        if(c == 'q')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}

// vim: ts=4 sw=4 et
```

Comment: C or C++? It can't be both.

Comment: I use C++ but those functions are clearly C, if you know the answer for C, it will work just fine for me.

Comment: @Barmar why not? You can use ncurses in both

Comment: @Pablo They're different languages, although they have many things in common.

Comment: @AlexisWilke as you may already know readline uses internally ncurses, so it may not be very easy to integrate them with ncurses apps. Looking for *readline integration in ncurses app* in google I found this: https://github.com/ulfalizer/readline-and-ncurses this look promising.

Comment: @Barmar I know that, I'm very active in the `c` tag here and always complain about the "C/C++" posts. However in this case I don't see any reason to be so pedantic as with SO beginners. And both ncurses and readline can be used in C and C++, so it's perfectly reasonable to ask for a solution in both.

Comment: @Pablo, ah, I did not realize that `readline()` was using `ncurse` under the hood. That would explain some other "strange" things, though. That link seems to be my answer, though. I'll have to look at it tomorrow. It's getting late here.

Comment: @AlexisWilke see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691652/using-gnu-readline-how-can-i-add-ncurses-in-the-same-program

Comment: readline is a [*termcap* application](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) (can't really say it "uses" ncurses).  Its initialization and hooks aren't well documented, so you'll have to read the source code to develop any non-trivial example using it.  Looking at the suggested duplicate, the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question.  The other answers appear useful.

Comment: If possible, just DON'T. Readline was developped to offer line interface command a way to easily reuse what had been typed in a previous line. It normally should not be used in curses interface

Comment: @Pablo That worked! I have to redraw the readline string each time a character is typed, but the final result works just fine. Not only that Ulfalizer (the author) has the resize handled too. So even the resize works!